# install ta-lib in windows 10 under Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

I just tried to install ta-lib in windows 10 
using anaconda `conda install -c r2d2 ta-lib`
and when I do `import talib` in ipython notebook, I get:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9bc7b4202a1f> in <module>()
----> 1 import talib

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\talib\__init__.py in <module>()
      2 import atexit
      3 
----> 4 from . import common
      5 from . import abstract
      6 from .common import MA_Type, __ta_version__

ImportError: cannot import name common
```

Comment: I have the same problem as well. How you solve the issue finally?

Answer (score 3):

I'm also using `Windows 10`, this command worked fine for me:

```
conda install -c quantopian ta-lib=0.4.9
```

Comment: What is python version? I cannot do that for python3

Comment: Any thoughts as to why i can get the conda prompt to work but have no module installed when in Jupiter notebook?

Comment: How can I import it? `import talib`  is not working and `import ta-lib` is syntactically wrong @matteo-baldi @youan-wang

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Windows 10. These commands worked for me:

```
conda install python=2.7.13
```

then:

```
conda install -c quantopian ta-lib=0.4.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can open Conda Prompt (in order to install in the base environment of Conda), then you can also use PIP:

```
pip install pandas-ta
```

It works the same as conda command.